# Ubuntu 14.04: Steam - OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display

Tags: drivers, opengl, steam, nvidia-quadro

I have a problem with Valve's Steam on Ubuntu 14.04. Whenever I try to start steam I get an error "OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display".

```
OpenGL GLX extension not supported by displayAssert( Assertion Failed: Fatal Error: OpenGL GLX extension not supported by display ):Main.cpp:307
```

glxinfo is giving me

```
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
Xlib:  extension "GLX" missing on display ":0".
...and so on...
```

Also, when I open sysinfo->NVIDIA->OpenGL/GLX Information it says:

```
Failed to query the GLX server vendor.
```

I have a NVIDIA Quadro K2100M, Driverversion: 346.46

Answer (score 0):

You probably trying to use NVidia driver on mobile platform with Optimus support.
Check if these packages are installed, and, if not, try to install them.
mesa-dri
xf86-video-intel
bumblebee

Comment: I dont have a built in Intel GPU. Therefore I dont need bumblebee, right?

Comment: yep, no need bumblebee then. Please post Your Xorg.0.log (error... lines).

Comment: Here are the errors of my Xorg.0.log file: http://pastebin.com/UYkYeLTP

Comment: try to run eselect  opengl set nvidia

Comment: How do I do that? ^_^

Comment: when I try to run "sudo eselect opengl set nvidia" it says that it doesnt find the command.

Comment: hmm, no eselect available in Ubuntu :(. I thought looking to Your error log, maybe in Your install glx from Xorg is used, but it will not work. Nvidia glx must be used. First, rename . Try to reinstall NVidia driver. Finally try to manual install of latest driver from NVidia site: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NvidiaManual .

Comment: check if You have these: [ 32.948] (II) LoadModule: "glx"
[ 32.962] (II) Loading /usr/lib/xorg/modules/extensions/libglx.so
[ 33.030] (II) Module glx: vendor="X.Org Foundation". glx: vendor MUST be Nvidia.

Comment: look for ModulePath "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules"
ModulePath "/usr/lib64/xorg/modules/extensions/nvidia" in xorg.conf. Your paths may be different. Try to rename libglx.so in xorg/modules.

Comment: some links: https://forums.geforce.com/default/topic/369385/geforce-drivers/failed-to-initialize-the-glx-module-can-39-t-init-glx-driver-on-fedoracore-6/   https://devtalk.nvidia.com/default/topic/830711/failed-to-initialize-the-glx-module-please-check-in-your-x-log-file-that-the-glx-module-has-been-lo/

Comment: I checked the X log file and the glx vendor is X.Org.Foundation. I tried to add                                                                                                       ModulePath      "/usr/lib/nvidia-current/xorg"
ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"                                                                but it didnt change anything:(

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/31874/discussion-between-tomsen1410-and-noangel).